# Extra pixels at top and bottom of label with image in tkinter

Tags: image, tkinter, label

In Python 3.2.5 and tkinter, I keep getting 1 or 2 "extra" border-like pixels at the top and bottom of a middle label (of three stacked labels) containing an image (the sides do not have a white border). No matter how I shrink the window or designate no borderwidth, I get a couple of pixels beyond the top and bottom of the label(s).

Here's the code....

```
        root.withdraw()

        LoginErrorMsg = tk.Toplevel()

        LoginErrorMsg.title('ERROR! Unauthorized Login Attempt')

        # pick .gif file
        # load the file and covert it to a tkinter image object
        imageFile = "ErrorLogin.gif"
        image1 = tk.PhotoImage(file=imageFile)

        #set size of Error Message Window
        width = 348
        height = 480

        #get size of the whole screen
        xmax = LoginErrorMsg.winfo_screenwidth()
        ymax = LoginErrorMsg.winfo_screenheight()

        #calculate centered window coordinates and position it
        x0 = xmax/2 - width/2
        y0 = ymax/2 - height/2
        LoginErrorMsg.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (width, height, x0, y0))

        # make the root window the size of the image
        #root.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (325, 475, x+100, y+100))

        # remove tk icon
        LoginErrorMsg.wm_iconbitmap('Ethicsicon.ico')

        #if user closes Error Message Window, clean up memory
        LoginErrorMsg.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", handler)

        # root has no image argument, so use a label as a panel
        panel1 = tk.Label(LoginErrorMsg, text="\nYou have exceeded three (3) login attempts.", background = "white", borderwidth = 0)
        #panel1.configure(background = 'white')
        panel1.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand='yes')
        panel2 = tk.Label(LoginErrorMsg, image=image1, background = "white", borderwidth = 0)
        panel2.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand='yes')
        panel3 = tk.Label(LoginErrorMsg, text="", borderwidth = 0)
        panel3.pack(side='top', fill= 'both', expand='yes')

        # save the panel's image from 'garbage collection'
        panel1.image = image1

        # put a button on the image panel
        button2 = tk.Button(panel3, text = '  OK  ', command = LeaveSystemCallback)
        button2.pack(side='top')

        LoginErrorMsg.update()
```

Comment: My workaround was simply to add another (4th) label at the bottom of the window...                                                              
            panel4 = tk.Label(LoginErrorMsg, text="", borderwidth = 0)
            panel4.pack(side='top', fill= 'both', expand='yes')

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `highlightthickness` attribute of each label to zero.